# How to make a rendering loop run at a consistent rate?

Tags: java, rendering, frame-rate

I've written a program with moving animated sprites based on user input that all takes place in a `while(true)` loop. Up until now the only way I've been timing the loop is by having a `sleep(20)` at the end of each run through the loop. I have noticed this effects the physics of my sprites negatively because my formula for calculating gravity is `velocity = velocity + GRAVITY * Elapsed-Time` and because the loop isn't running at a consistent rate the effect of gravity is not consistent either. **Is there a way to keep the loop running consistently or better way of timing it so it actually runs on a schedule?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, determine how long you want your frames to last. If you want 30 fps, then you'll have

```
final long frameDuration = 1000 / 30;
```

Next, when you start rendering, store the time, like so

```
final long then = System.currentTimeMillis();
render(); // surely it's more than this but you get the idea
final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

final long actualDuration = now - then;
final long sleepDuration = frameDuration - actualDuration;

if(sleepDuration > 0) {
    sleep(sleepDuration);
} else {
    throw new FrameTooLongException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
velocity = velocity + GRAVITY * Elapsed-Time
```

This should work regardless of whether your frame rate is constant or not.  The trick is to measure elapsed time accurately & consistently.  Measure elapsed time from some point in your loop to the same point in the next loop.

Comment: Yes. I don't really understand why. I always get the elapsed time at the same point yet the height that my sprite jumps seems to remain inconsistent.

Comment: You also have to use the same elapsed time for `position = position + velocity * Elapsed-Time`.  And of course rounding errors and time discretization errors can creep in (but I would expect those to be small if you use `double`s and milliseconds).